# redirect session message not showing properly in laravel 8

Tags: laravel-8

I have this function in my controller

```
public function deleteTour($id)
{
    $tours=Tour::find($id);
    $tours->delete();
    return Redirect::back()->with('success','deleted');
}
```

In my view

```
@if(session()->has('success'))
   <div class="alert alert-success">
      {{ session()->get('success') }}
   </div>
@endif
```

Sometimes it is showing success message correctly, but sometimes it is not returning the message.
I couldn't find the issue.
after deleting the record redirect() not showing updated view(Show old data)
Is there any session issue? please help

Comment: I'm sorry, but if this is a success redirect, why you are using back() method too?

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved. In my case it was a conflict with a javascript plugin(Touchswipe).Removing that plugin solved the issue.